# OSGI bundle error: Unresolved package in bundle 73:package=org.apache.commons.httpclient

Tags: java, osgi, apache-camel

1. I have to use camel-http component.
2. I added the dependencies in the POM file. (Code Listing 1)
3. I started getting **Unresolved package error**  for
   "package=org.apache.commons.httpclient" at **Runtime**.
4. So I have added the dependency for commons-httpclient (Code Listing 2). I added it in embedded-dependency because commons-httpclient is a non-osgi jar.
5. I am still getting the same error.
6. I also tried adding this package in  tag.

**Note** - I can see the dependencies getting reflected under Import-Package, in the generated MANIFEST file of my bundle jar.

Code Listing 1:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
      <version>${camel-version}</version>
      <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
    </dependency>
```

Code Listing 2:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>            
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you tried the [Felix version](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-commons.html) or [this OSGI bundle](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-osgi)?

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your reply. I am using OSGI bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Servicemix has an OSGi bundle wrapper for the commons-httpclient, can you try to install it instead of embedding it in your bundle ?

mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient/3.1_4

Comment: I'd recommend doing a `features:install mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient/3.1_4` and then install your bundle. See if that works.

Comment: The command should be osgi:install -s mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient/3.1_4

Comment: Thanks for your response Willem. Itried using the servicemix commons-httpclient bundle but the error still persists.

Comment: Are you using ServiceMix or Karaf ? With the apache-camel karaf feature, the camel-http feature should work out of box.